# is mysqli_insert_id reliable?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert, auto-increment

I am building a log-in system which uses three tables in a mysql database (PHP) called users, sessions and log-ins.  All tables have an auto-increment index.  After a successful log-in happens, the user row is linked to a session row via the values stored in a new log-in row.  I am wondering if `mysqli_insert_id()` is safe to use in this process.  I am worried that if there is an error during the session row `INSERT`, the log-in row will receive an incorrect session index number and the user will get logged into the wrong session.

is this going to be a problem?  If so, is there a good way to handle it?

Comment: How do you think such an error might occur? You *can* check that the insert has worked.

Comment: If you're worried about data consistency use `TRANSACTION`s. `mysql_insert_id` is safe to use for each PHP run.

Comment: If you're worried about this problem, you should not be using `mysqli` directly. Instead, use a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) or an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) to handle this for you reliably.

Comment: @Quentin mysqli obsolete?

Comment: @SakhalTurkaystan — Look at the edit history on the question. It was changed to `mysql` 30 minutes after I made the comment.

Comment: Yes it was, I should have been referring to using mysqli from the start

Comment: Look: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 2):

That method will produce reliable results **if**:

- The last `INSERT` operation succeeded.
- The result is checked *immediately* after the `INSERT` succeeded on the same database connection.

Most of the time it will be sufficient to call `INSERT` and then fetch the ID of what was inserted as the next operation so long as you're using the same database handle.

A framework will do all of this for you automatically, so it's usually not something you should be concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure the integrity of your data & the operations that you perform, then I suggest you go with the "All or None" approach. This means that all your queries will pass individually or they will all fail, even if one fails. You can implement this using TRANSACTION & ROLLBACK features in MySQL. For more info, you may visit: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm

Answer (score -1):

it's better if you use triggers

trigger will do a query when you trigger another

[see this tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx)

Comment: Would it be a good idea to create a trigger that returns the row that was just created?  Or create several triggers that completely update the database when a user logs in?

Comment: Triggers are a **massive** pain in the ass for something simple like this, plus don't solve the problem of retrieving the ID of the last row inserted.

Comment: yes you can create several triggers to update several tables as you want .. so when user logs in you just insert in your logs table and triggers will do the rest for you